# How to download a public domain Google Books ebook?

Tags: google-books

Recently, [some scans](https://books.google.com/books?id=I4aMAlzjYrAC) by Google Books, while being in the [public domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public_domain), are labeled as "[Google eBook](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Play_Books)", for instance all the "digital objects" of [a certain BNN series](http://polosbn.bnnonline.it/SebinaOpac/Opac?action=search&sq=n&idOpacSup=IEI0120367&startat=0).

These books seem very hard to access: they [are not returned](https://www.google.com/search?tbo=p&tbm=bks&q=intitle:%22Nuova%20Enciclopedia%20Popolare%22&tbs=,bkv:p&num=10) by a Google Books search for books with preview available; clicking "ebook" brings me, after many hops including logging in, to an [online reader](https://play.google.com/books/reader?printsec=frontcover&output=reader&id=I4aMAlzjYrAC) without download option.

Finally, if I follow Google's instructions to [Download & transfer books to eReaders](https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/179863), I have no download button at all next to the `⋮`, while I see one for [other books](http://books.google.it/books/?id=1jsOAQAAIAAJ) (which ask a captcha).

So, how do I download those books? Also, if Adobe Digital Editions is required (!), why is it and what can a GNU/Linux user do?

Comment: See also http://askubuntu.com/questions/92444/how-to-install-adobe-digital-editions http://askubuntu.com/questions/589117/have-installed-adobe-digital-editions-but-cannot-run-it-under-wine and friends.

Comment: Note, often (for USA libraries) Hathi Trust lets you read scans which on Google Books can only be searched, but PDF download is impossible for most people: https://www.hathitrust.org/access_use#pd-google (despite legal victory https://www.hathitrust.org/authors_guild_google + https://www.eff.org/deeplinks/2012/10/authors-guild-vhathitrustdecision ).

Answer (score 2):

Really following [your link](https://books.google.it/books?id=I4aMAlzjYrAC) I see that I could download PDF using an option under the right-top "wheel" button. But I see it as logged Google user.

[image: screenshot of the menu]